# Not all threads are printing in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to add in multi-threading using OpenMP for a work project. I'm using Fortran77 in Visual Studio 2017, and while trying to debug, have found a behavior that I don't totally understand.

I'm new to OpenMP, so this may be an misunderstanding about the mechanics of multi-threading, but my understanding is that if I have a write statement in a do loop, every thread should print out that write statement. I've recreated my issue in a small project for simplicity.

The subroutine that has this issue is supposed to print which thread is operating and then the value of a variable (which is 1) before calling another simple subroutine:

```
  SUBROUTINE TAKEVAR(VAR)
  USE OMP_LIB
  INTEGER:: VAR
      
  VAR = VAR + 1
  !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(4)
  !$OMP DO
  DO i = 1, 5
  WRITE(*, *) 'Hello from thread ', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
  WRITE(*, *) VAR 
  CALL ROUTINE2(VAR)
  ENDDO
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
  END SUBROUTINE
```

However, the output of this subroutine is as follows:

[Output (can't embed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ChKS.png)

I see that the loop is executed 5 times using 4 threads, which is correct, but each statement showing the thread number is not followed by the value of the variable. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: One solution is to use a critical section for your printouts: (`!$omp critical` and `!$omp end critical` before and after `WRITE(...` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since each thread is executed at the same time than the others, nothing can garantee that no other WRITE from another thread will occur between the first and second WRITE of a given thread.

In a comment @Laci gave a possible solution:

```
  !$OMP CRITICAL
  WRITE(*, *) 'Hello from thread ', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
  WRITE(*, *) VAR 
  !$OMP END CRITICAL
```

The code inside a critical section can be executed by only one thread at a time, so nothing can be executed between the 2 WRITE. However critical sections can hurt performances...

Another solution can be to use a single WRITE instruction:

```
WRITE(*, *) 'Hello from thread ', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM(), VAR
```

That said I have had bad experiences (crashes on execution) with WRITEs in parallel regions, so I tend to always put them in critical sections.